# How to sum of all values using hasManyRelation in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am using laravel query builder. i got stuck somewhere. My query is like below :-

```
$details = File::query();
if($ftskey=="partially"){
        $details = $details->with(['partialfiles'=>function($query) use($startdate,$enddate){
            $query->whereDate('partial_date', '>=', $startdate)
                    ->whereDate('partial_date', '<=', $enddate);
        }]);
    }
$details = $details->get();
$response = json_decode(json_encode($details),true);

 //Relationship below
 public function partialfiles(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\PartialFile','file_id');
}
```

Output is coming below:-

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 238
        [file_no] => FSC334
        [partialfiles] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [file_id] => 238
                        [partial_date] => 2019-09-23
                        [partial_amount] => 50
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [file_id] => 238
                        [partial_date] => 2019-09-23
                        [partial_amount] => 50
                    )

            )
    )
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 239
        [file_no] => FSC335
        [partialfiles] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [file_id] => 238
                        [partial_date] => 2019-09-23
                        [partial_amount] => 100
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [file_id] => 238
                        [partial_date] => 2019-09-23
                        [partial_amount] => 100
                    )

            )
    )
)
```

Now i want to add sum of all partial_amount key that i used in hasMany relationship i.e is 50+50+100+100 =300 my expected output is like below:-

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 238
        [file_no] => FSC334
        [total_amount] => 300
        [partialfiles] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [file_id] => 238
                        [partial_date] => 2019-09-23
                        [partial_amount] => 50
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [file_id] => 238
                        [partial_date] => 2019-09-23
                        [partial_amount] => 50
                    )

            )
    )
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 239
        [file_no] => FSC335
        [total_amount] => 300
        [partialfiles] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [file_id] => 238
                        [partial_date] => 2019-09-23
                        [partial_amount] => 100
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [file_id] => 238
                        [partial_date] => 2019-09-23
                        [partial_amount] => 100
                    )

            )
    )
)
```

Now see i have added the key total_amount in array. Kindly help me how can i get the sum of all amount.

note :- Please don't suggest me foreach loop to do. As i want to do at  query level only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum() from Collection

```
$details->partialfiles()->sum('partial_amount');
```

also read this documentation from laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections

Comment: This is not at the query level as OP has asked.

Comment: @ascsoftw this is the fastest and clean answer for getting sum of all the amount since he is returning collection

Comment: This answer is wrong. $details cannot get all particalfiles, it still need to loop. And his question is want to do at query level.

Comment: @Paul its doesn't seems to be correct check my question please

Comment: @TsaiKoga that is query-level.  note the `()` after the relationship, which returns a query builder, not a relationship.  thus the `sum()` is happening in the database, not in eloquent.

Comment: @TsaiKoga however, this is not a good solution for many rows due to n+1